# How to get quarterly income statement with yahoo_fin

Tags: python, finance

I started learning python and am currently working with yahoo_fin to look at financial data.

I can use stock_info.get_income_statement() to get the annual income statements but I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to get the quarterly income statement that you can view on yahoo's site.

Is this possible using yahoo_fin or do I need to use a different library?

Comment: I think you may need to use selenium as well ,to change the view from Annual to Quarterly and then try to scrape the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
data = YahooFinancials('MSFT')
income_stat = data.get_financial_stmts(frequency = 'quarterly', statement_type = 
'income')
```

After getting data, you might need to process it for better presentation

Comment: How can you search for multiple companies using this code? Also is there a way to just filter through and print just one field from the retrieved data? @r_hudson

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`get_data`](http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/) function with arguments `start_date` and `end_date`.

#### Syntax:

```
get_data(ticker, start_date = None, end_date = None, index_as_date = True)
```

Downloads historical price data of a stock into a pandas data frame.

```py
from1999 = get_data('msft' , start_date = '01/01/1999')

few_days = get_data('msft' , start_date = '01/01/1999' , end_date = '01/10/1999')
```

Comment: From my understanding that just returns stock price information. The income statement provides companies total revenue and operating expense which I don't think can be extrapolated from the stock price information.

Comment: Perhaps try a more complex package. I couldn't find anything more relevant than the function above when I searched the API. Look here: https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/awesome-quant

Comment: TIA looks relevant: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bpsmith/tia/blob/master/examples/backtest.ipynb

Comment: Thanks, that github link looks pretty useful. I'll see if any of those can help me out.